# PHP cascading select & datetimepicker not working on dynamic data loaded in modal via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datetimepicker, cascading

Due to performance issues (because my data loads around 2k data), I was forced to load user information from another page to a modal via ajax. This is the [tutorial](https://makitweb.com/dynamically-load-content-in-bootstrap-modal-with-ajax/) that I have followed. From the tutorial, I made two page (`index.php` and `file.php`). Data in `index.php` are loaded via datatables with a button on the side that opens a modal. The data inside the modal will be coming from `file.php` which is loaded via ajax. The goal was for users to edit user data saved from the database.

In another modal (via add button in `index.php`), there is a cascading select and a datetimepicker that is working. I tried adding it to the other page (`file.php`) which is being loaded via ajax, unfortunately, the code is not working and nothing happens`.

**Concept**

```
col1   col2    col3       action
id     name    address    edit/delete
```

**Index.php**

```
<html>
 <head></head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <td>
         <button>
      </td>
    </table> 
    
     <script></script> //insert ajax here which will be triggered by the button from table

     <modal> //blank modal that will be populated via ajax from file.php

  </body>
</html>
```

**File.php**

```
<?php some_query ?>//query here for populating form
<form>
   <select>  //cascading
   <select 2> //triggered via first selection
   <input text> //datetimepicker
</form>
```

**Code for the cascading under add user in index.php**

```
<select class="form-control" name="province" onChange="getSubcat(this.value);" >

<script>
    function getSubcat(val) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/sis/php/get-subcat.php",
        data:'cat_id1='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#governate2").html(data);
        }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I tried modifying `file.php` by adding an `html`,`head`,and `body` tag and the jquery links to see if it will work but was not successful.

Comment: It's better to make your question stand on itself, instead of letting it depend on external content. The external content requires us to pass a cookie wall and it is unclear which parts are relevant. It might also disappear in a couple of years when your question, and our answers, are still here. Also see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi @KIKOSoftware, I have modified the question to include the concept of the system. Thank you

Comment: Ensure to have the browser's console open to see if there are any JavaScript errors logging. In the same area, there is also a network tab where you can check the ajax requests.

Comment: @PaulT. Hi. I have followed your advise and was able to fix the cascading dropdown. It showed in the console that it was not able to see function. So far, I am still troubleshooting the datetimepicker as no error shows in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I was able to solve the problem. As mentioned in the comments, I have used the console and was able to figure out the problems.

**For the Cascading Select**

The console showed that it can't find the `ajax trigger` so I just added the code above in the `index.php page`. And now it works perfectly

**For the Datetimepicker**

This part is tricky since it didn't show any error in the console. I tried adding the code and script source in the `file.php` and now it works perfectly.

Comment: It would be ideal to post how the final code looks for other that might face the same issue. Also, you can accept your own answer too. :-)